# Update nodal values without for loop using numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to update nodal values on a [mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh) from element values.

In an array `faces` i define the ids of the nodes of an element (let's assume I only have two elements):

```
faces = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2]])
```

The array `force_el` contains, let's say, the force acting equally on each node of the element:

```
force_el = np.array([[0.7, 1.1], [1.2, 0.3]])
```

Now I would like to update the nodal forces `force_node`:

```
force_node = np.zeros((4, force_el.shape[1]))
for face, fel in zip(faces, force_el):
    force_node[face.ravel(), :] += fel
```

So that the result is:

```
>>> force_node
array([[0.7, 1.1],
       [1.9, 1.4],
       [1.9, 1.4],
       [1.2, 0.3]])
```

Since this update has to be done many times (in the order of 100k-1m times), I'm trying to optimize it, but I cannot see a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some `matrix-multiplication` *force* -

```
out_nrows = 4 # number of nodes
mask = np.zeros((len(faces),out_nrows),dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask,faces,True,axis=1)
force_node_out = mask.T.dot(force_el)
```

With a small number of cols in `force_el`, we can also use `np.bincount` for an even better performance -

```
out_nrows = 4 # number of nodes
out = np.zeros((out_nrows, force_el.shape[1]))
n = faces.shape[1]
l = force_el.shape[1]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(l):
        out[:,j] += np.bincount(faces[:,i],force_el[:,j],minlength=out_nrows)
```

Timings -

```
In [35]: # Setup data (from OP's comments)
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: faces=np.array([np.random.choice(1800,3,replace=0) for i in range(3500)])
    ...: force_el = np.random.rand(len(faces),3)

In [36]: %%timeit # Original loopy soln
    ...: out_nrows = 1800
    ...: force_node = np.zeros((out_nrows, force_el.shape[1]))
    ...: for face, fel in zip(faces, force_el):
    ...:     force_node[face.ravel(), :] += fel
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

In [37]: %%timeit # @RafaelC's soln with np.add.at
    ...: force_node = np.zeros((1800, force_el.shape[1]))
    ...: np.add.at(force_node, faces, force_el[:,None])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop

In [38]: %%timeit # Posted in this post that uses matrix-multiplication
    ...: out_nrows = 1800
    ...: mask = np.zeros((len(faces),out_nrows),dtype=bool)
    ...: np.put_along_axis(mask,faces,True,axis=1)
    ...: force_node_out = mask.T.dot(force_el)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ms per loop

In [39]: %%timeit # Posted in this post that uses bincount
    ...: out_nrows = 1800
    ...: out = np.zeros((out_nrows, force_el.shape[1]))
    ...: n = faces.shape[1]
    ...: l = force_el.shape[1]
    ...: for i in range(n):
    ...:     for j in range(l):
    ...:         out[:,j]+=np.bincount(faces[:,i],force_el[:,j],minlength=out_nrows)
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. In my post I did not mention that the system is much larger than 4 nodes. By testing your solution and @RafaelC's solution assuming 1800 nodes and 10000 time steps, I got following results:
- Loopy solution: ~159 s
- Your solution: ~231s
- RafaelC's solution: ~23 s

So I guess for large systems rafael's way is the one to take.

Comment: @David With your actual dataset- What's the shape of faces, force_el?

Comment: The shape of both arrays is (3500, 3), whereas force_node.shape == (1800, 3). Sorry that the size of the system wasn't clear. Just to give you some more background, I'm modeling an hollow cylinder with triangular elements. Therefore the number of faces is correlated to the number of nodes and viceversa.

Comment: @David Added timings for such a dataset. Take a look? Did you time `bincoount` one at your end?

Comment: That's a HUGE performance gain, thanks! With the exact same configuration as above, your `bincount` solution only takes ~1.5 s. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of `numpy` broadcasting whenever possible.

Use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)

```
np.add.at(force_node, faces, force_el[:,None])
```

Comment: Thanks, @RafaelC! This was actually the method I was looking for. Your answer could've been marked as the Accepted answer and I'm sure will be helpful to me/to other users coming to this question in the future. Since I really care about performance, @Divakar's solution is however the best one for my specific case.

Comment: @David By all means! Glad I could help. The upside of `np.add.at` is that it is readable and intuitive, but performance-wise Divakar's matrix mult is way better. Anyway, Divakar is a God, should aways accept his answers haha. Good coding :}